# Mirror my screen with multiple resolutions

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, frontend

### What I have

- Windows 10 ( What I use mainly, but I do have access to other OS's if necessary.
- 2 Screens

### What I want

I want to be able to mirror one of my screens to the other, but I want the second screen to be splitted in (for example) 4. Each portion of the screen would show my main screen with a **different** resolution.

Let's say: 
My *second screen* has a resolution of (another example) **1366x768**, and it will be splitted in 4 portions
**Portion1:** would cover from [ **0x0** ] to [ **633x384** ] and show my screen with a resolution of **1280x600**
**Portion2:** would cover from [ **0x384** ] to [ **633x768** ] and show my screen with a resolution of **1400x1500**
**Portion3:** would cover from [ **633x0** ] to [ **1366x384** ] and show my screen with a resolution of **1920x1080**
**Portion4:** would cover from [ **633x384** ] to [ **1366x768** ] and show my screen with a resolution of **3840x2160**

### Why I want that

I'm a front-end developer, and I want to make sure the changes Im working on are working, but I need to make sure that they are working on every screen resolution... So I would like to be able to see how my program/website/etc would look on multiple resolutions at once...

I actually have a 4k monitor, so I dont think that losing data through resizing would make much difference...

Well... Is there another approach to solve my problem? I'm open to suggestions :P

## Thanks for reading <3

Comment: Why don't you just open multiple windows of Firefox in responsive design mode with the fixed resolutions you want to test on?

Comment: @confetti as of now... my application doesnt work with Firefox, is there such thing in Chrome/IE/Safari??

Comment: Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

Comment: Actually, doing that, I would have to redo the same command in the same specific way I did multiple times (one time on each screen)

Comment: Unless you wanna get into more complicated setups or virtual machines running different resolutions in headless mode.... I don't think that's possible.